# How to output a value that is a method in rabl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rabl

I am trying to output the value of a method on my Item model (current_user is defined in application_controller). I currently have as my rabl template:

```
object @item
attributes :id, :name

code :is_liked do |this_item|
  if current_user
    this_item.is_liked current_user
  else
    false
  end
end
```

and in my model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def is_liked user
    if user
      if user.liked_item_ids.include?(self.id)
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end
  ....
end
```

but it isn't working. I'm not sure what a proper way of outputting this would be. Any idea how to get this to work correctly?

**edit 1**

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   stack level too deep
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rabl seems to be fine, however, when your find yourself adding some logic in your views (rabl can be compared to a view) you might want to consider refactor the logic in a presenter.

More information about presenters with rabl [here](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Managing-Complexity-with-Presenters)

Regarding your error, like @apneadiving just said, there is a recursion issue in your codebase somewhere. Just by curiosity, have you try to rename the `code` block into something else than your method's name ? Depending on which version on rabl you are using, this could be the issue.

Finaly, you should consider refactoring your `is_liked` method:

```
def is_liked user
  return user.liked_item_ids.include?(id) if user
  false
end
```

Comment: thx for the heads up on presenters, I moved this frag to Active Model Serializers and it works fine making me think it's a rabl issue

Comment: you welcome, please consider accepting the answer if you think it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
node(:is_liked) {|this_item| this_item.is_liked(current_user) }
```

You already have the method, you can simply invoke here within a node instead of recreating logic.

Comment: thx, I tried but updated question with error I am getting. I am not sure if current_user is accessible in my rabl templates and am testing that now.

Comment: current_user should be available. Just noticed you should remove `:is_liked` from the `attributes` list + check your `is_liked` method

Comment: thx for comment; yes, I've tried both with and with is_liked in the attributes but I agree with your comment; will update question. I'm going to look at moving current_user to a helper class rather than have it in application_controller and as a helper_method there. thx

Comment: you have a recursion issue, I doubt it stems from the code I can see

Comment: I agree - I think it's something related to current_user; using it all over our views so it's odd that it's blowing up in rabl only. Well, it's 1 in the morning for me - probably not doing the best thinking right now.